# Getting Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions error when trying to render a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render `Card` component based on the number of items in the `items` object but I am getting the error on line 6.

```
import React from "react";
    export class Cards extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let elements = [];
        elements = this.props.items.map(item => {
          <Card titles = {item.title} imgsrc = {item.urlToImage}
          discr = {item.description} urls = {item.url}
          />
        })
        return (
          {elements}
        );
      }
    }
```

And this is the `Card` component :

```
import React from 'react'
export default ({titles, imgsrc, urls, discr}) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="cardHead">
            <h4>{titles}</h4>
          </div>
          <div className="cardBody">
            <img src={imgsrc} alt="pst-img" />
          </div>
          <div className="cardFooter">
            <p>{discr}</p>
            <a className="buttn" href={urls}>
              <button>Read More</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: Your `.map` callback is not returning anything. Try returning the JSX instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning the JSX in the `.map` you need to do it like this:

```
import React from "react";
    export class Cards extends React.Component {
      render() {
        let elements = [];
        elements = this.props.items.map(item => {
         return <Card titles = {item.title} imgsrc = {item.urlToImage}
          discr = {item.description} urls = {item.url}
          />
        })
        return (
          {elements}
        );
      }
    }
```

Or in a Cleaner Way:

```
import React from "react";
    export class Cards extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
         {this.props.items.map(item => {
         return <Card titles = {item.title} imgsrc = {item.urlToImage}
          discr = {item.description} urls = {item.url}
          />
        })}
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As the first answer, you need to return the JSX in `map()`

Or using `( )` instead of `{}` inside the `map()`

like this

```
import React from "react";
    export class Cards extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
         {this.props.items.map(item => (
         return <Card titles = {item.title} imgsrc = {item.urlToImage}
          discr = {item.description} urls = {item.url}
          />
        ))}
        );
      }
    }
```